# Djanggo python - database

Tags: python, django

**Ive been working on Web base Djanggo Pyhton project. So my problem is, the website somehow display error which is timeout error which means there something wrong in the code but i cant find where the error.
Here is the code**

**views fle**

```
# Create your views here.
from datetime import datetime as dt, time
#from dateutil.parser import parse, tz
from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponse
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required
from django.core import serializers
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory, modelformset_factory
from django.forms import formset_factory, BaseModelFormSet
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render, redirect
from itertools import islice
from django.db.models import F
import collections
import json
import os

from .forms import MitsubishiLiftForm
from .models import MitsubishiLift
from report.audit_log import log_addition, log_change, log_deletion, backup_log, restore_log
from .settings import settings_write, settings_read
from hardware.forms import ImportConfigurationForm



 @permission_required('setting.add_mconfig', raise_exception = True)
def liftconfiguration_mconfig(request):
    title = "Enter Configuration"
    index_temp = "liconfiguration/index.html"
    form = MitsubishiLiftForm(request.POST or None)
 
    if form.is_valid():
        new_obj = form.save()
        log_addition(request, form, new_obj)
        return redirect('setting:liconfiguration_index')

    context = {
        "title": title,
        "form": form,
        "index_temp": index_temp,
    }
    return render(request, "liconfiguration/indexr2.html", context)
```

**models file**

```
from django.db import models

class MitsubishiLift(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    ELSGW_ipaddress = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    ELSGW_port = models.CharField(max_lenght = 20)
    local_port = models.CharField(max_lenght = 20)
    ELSGW_devnum = models.IntegerField(null = True, blank = True)
    reader_num = models.IntegerField(null = True, blank = True)
    boarding_floor = models.IntegerField(null = True, blank = True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.ELSGW_ipaddress
```

**urls file**

```
url(r'^liconfiguration/new$', views.liftconfiguration_mconfig, name = 'liftconfiguration_mconfig'),
```

***init* files (forms)**

```
from setting.forms.mitsubishi_form import MitsubishiLiftForm
```

**database**

```
id integer NOT NULL,
"ELSGW_ipaddress" character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
"ELSGW_port" character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
local_port character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
"ELSGW_devnum" integer,
reader_num integer,
boarding_floor integer,
CONSTRAINT liftintegration_mitsubishi_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

Comment: is it working locally?

Comment: I'm not sure because the website become unreachable. How to know either it is working or not locally?

Comment: So are you new to django?

Comment: Yes, im new with djanngo

Comment: Just learn the basics of `django` and ypu can be able to solve this issue, all you need is some clarity